DHARMa bootstrap testOutliers unexpected p-values
I am checking the assumptions of multiple univariate logistic mixed models each with a predictor and covariates.
Due to the following error:
To get a more exact result, it is recommended to re-run testOutliers with type = 'bootstrap'. See ?testOutliers for details"

I run testOutliers(simulated_residuals, type = "bootstrap", nBoot = 1000) separately as suggested.
When I do this, all of the p-values for all of the tests are exactly 1.
Whilst it is stated that type="binomial" may inflate type I errors, I found this a little surprising since the p-values when type="binomial" varied between runs but were around ~0.01, 0.04 or 0.11.
The QQ-plots, residual vs predicted plot, histogram of the outlier test and residual vs independent variable of the interested plot show that some of the models are problematic, although they are okay in most cases (however, p-values = 1 in all cases).
Is it really the case that all of the simulated residuals are within the observed data for every single run or am I missing something?
